# How protect wifi password hacking?

Tags: wireless-networking, password-protection

I want to get such a process that someone who is not authorized  or registered person cannot access the wifi though  he collects the password any corrupted way.I want to say that only some authorized device(i.e. 5 pc and 2 mobile in my room) access the wifi network.

Comment: You can do this with Mac Filtering only add the computers or phones mac addresses you want to be able to use the internet. Look [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/204458/why-you-shouldn%E2%80%99t-use-mac-address-filtering-on-your-wi-fi-router/) gives you reasons why people do it and why you shouldn't do it.

Comment: Use strong wireless encryption in the router and use a long-strong password key, this is your best defense, other than using ethernet cables and disabling the wireless in the router.

Answer (score 2):

Every device that can connect to a network has it's own MAC address. You can configure your router to allow access only for specific MAC addresses - that is called MAC filtering

Comment: This is pretty much the only way to do it. As long as the perpetrator isn't MAC-spoofing. Then you'd need something heavier.

Comment: Mac filtering is a waste of time..http://www.howtogeek.com/204458/why-you-shouldn%E2%80%99t-use-mac-address-filtering-on-your-wi-fi-router/

Comment: WPA2 + MAC filtering > WPA2. The OP clearly stated that his/her password was sniffed.